# Is there a difference between '=' and In?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any differences (perf) writting this request:

```
Select * from T where PK = 1
```

or this

```
Select * from T where PK in (1)
```

I believe not but i realy don't know how to dispay an execution plan that should assert my feeling.

Thx in advance

Comment: I'd hope that the optimiser would recognise that there's only a single value in your `IN` list and treat it the same as it would `=`.

Comment: So do I. But how can I assert it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IN expression:

```
Column in (Val1,Val2,Val3)
```

Is internally rewritten into something very similar to:

```
(Column = Val1 or Column = Val2 or Column = Val3)
```

You can tell this because, if you supply the name of a non-existent column, the number of errors reported (`Invalid Column name 'Blah'`) is equal to the number of values in the IN list. Of course, such re-writing only occurs for lists of literal values. Subqueries (as @oezi says) are handled differently.

---

Of course, this particular optimization isn't documented, and it is always preferable to write the clearest code possible.

I'm not sure if there's an upper limit where it will not perform this expansion - it will certainly do it up to 100 values in the IN list (and I can't be bothered to type in more).

Answer (score 3):

in your case: no difference

in general: you could write a subselect or inside of the braces, and `=` will fail if that subselect returns more than 1 row. also, you could write `(1,2)` (wich would be like a subselect that returns 2 rows), where `=` isn't possible, too.

Comment: Thx, I know how to use in and '='. I was just wondering if there whould be a perf difference

Answer (score -1):

Comparison operator that compares two values for equality is the fastest way to do comparison.

"Select * from T where PK = 1"

will preform much faster than:

"Select * from T where PK in (1)"

a same as:

"SELECT customer_number, customer_name FROM customer WHERE customer_number BETWEEN 1000 and 1004"

will preform much faster than:

"SELECT customer_number, customer_name FROM customer WHERE customer_number in (1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004)"

The Query Optimizer can locate a range of numbers much faster (using BETWEEN) than it can find a series of numbers using the IN clause.

Comment: Ok, but how can you proove it ?

Comment: Ok, Damien_The_Unbeliever was right, i just checked in execution plan that "Select * from T where PK in (1)" is executed/translated as "Select * from T where PK = 1", that means query optimizer did his job. Subqueries in IN clause are handled differently.

Comment: Only thing that could be faster if when query is parsed. :-)